# DomDocument::loadHTML() error during phpunit test execution

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework

I am currently trying to write some unit test against my zend framework controller.  When I run the following code I receive this error:

```
public function testListActionShouldContainListTable()
    {

        $this->loginToSystem();

        $uri = $this->_uriBase . 'campaign/list';
        $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = $uri;

        $this->dispatch('/campaign/list');
        $this->assertController('campaign');
        $this->assertAction('list');
        $this->assertQueryCount('#list',1);
    }


CampaignControllerTests::testListActionShouldContainListTable
DOMDocument::loadHTML(): ID alrt already defined in Entity, line: 36
```

This occurs using any of the assertQuery and assertQueryContains methods. I have searched around but am not really finding a good answer to why it won't allow me to find this html node or how to get around this error.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML being generated by the dispatch is bad (it looks like it has two ids being assigned to a single tag).  This is not an error of your test (it's working fine), it's an error in your html output generated by the test...

Comment: i have done an echo of $this->getResponse->outputBody() and getBody() and can find no duplicates for the id.  I have tried css searches for just "body", "div" as well as xpath searches and they all production the same error. Right time i remove the assertQuery call, the tests pass.

Comment: Look for either more than 1 element with the same id, or an element with more than 1 id attribute...

Comment: Thanks you were right. It only took 2 times going through the mark up before I stopped overlooking the dup id.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the document is valid. You have duplicate IDs in your HMTL document.